# Canceling subscription Combine framework

Tags: swiftui, combine

Is there way we can cancel dataTaskPublisher while app is going in background in Combine framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send `.cancel()` to subscriber. Here is a demo class

```
class Downloader: ObservableObject{
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    let url: URL

    init(url: URL){
        self.url = url
    }

    func download(){
        cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        // ... other operators code
    }
    
    func cancel() {
        self.cancellable?.cancel()
        self.cancellable = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I need to cancel the publisher while going to background. I am not able to listen the background event. I am  aware AnyCancellable.cancel()

Answer (score 1):

If you want to embed the cancellation behavior right into the Combine publisher operator chain then `prefix(untilOutputFrom:)` can be helpful:

```
let url: URL = ...
cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    .prefix(untilOutputFrom: NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification))
    .sink(receiveCompletion: {
        print($0)
    },receiveValue: {
        print($0)
    })
```

This starts the the data task but then cancels it if `UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification` is triggered. I don't see many people using this operator, probably because it is poorly named, but it is a common pattern in other reactive frameworks such as ReactiveSwift where the operator is more sensibly named `take(until:)`.